# Редактирование игры, написанной на Construct 2, в Eclipse

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Есть игра, написанная на игровом движке [Construct 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construct_(game_engine)#Construct_2).

Как ее можно отредактировать в Eclipse?

Суть в том, что после разработки в *Construct 2* на выходе получаем обычный *.apk* архив. Декомпиляция - не вариант (по понятным причинам).

Comment: Да, скорее всего, никак. Собственно, почему вы думаете, что это вообще возможно?

Comment: Я не думаю, что это возможно. Я надеялся на это. Пишу приложение (не игру) в котором часть функционала проще реализовать с помощью игровых движков. Но, увы - не судьба.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону libgdx И adengine, там вы сможете использовать и функционал движков и приложений.

Answer (score 1):

> Как ее можно отредактировать в Eclipse?

без «исходников» — никак.

Comment: А вот как (каким образом), если это вообще возможно, "вытащить" код из движка до компиляции его в .apk? Может существует какое-нибудь решение?

Comment: если код компилируется на доступной для вас машине в доступных для вас каталогах, то он должен быть вам доступен.

Comment: Construct 2. http://c2community.ru/ не даёт такой возможности или я чего то не понимаю.

Comment: вы не понимаете, а я просто не знаю: что именно вы делаете для компиляции. 1. переходите по какой-то ссылке на каком-то сайте? значит, сборка происходит там и вам исходники недоступны. 2. запускаете какую-то программу у себя на машине? тогда следующий вопрос: если отключить интернет перед компиляцией, то она пройдёт успешно? если да, то исходники находятся на вашей машине. просто найдите, где именно.